# Give specific permission per user when signing up

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using allauth for registering users and I would like to give permissions to users automatically after they created a local account or using social login.
A good example would be only 1 user to be able to create posts and comments whilst the rest of the users to be able to only create comments.
Looking around I have seen that you can create Groups and through those you can give certain permissions, is this the right way to handle this? Or are there some better avenues worth exploring?

Many thanks.

Comment: Allauth lets you pass extra parameters to the auth handshake using the AUTH_PARAMS key in the settings of a social account provider. For example, put the following in your settings.py to add the repo scope to the returned GitHub token:
`SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "github": {
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"scope": "repo"}
    },
}`

Comment: Please have a look at this:
https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/